# How to inflate layout containing vector drawable icon?

Tags: android, layout, kotlin, androidx

I want to inflate `layout` containing `ImageView` with `vector xml` background drawable.

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false)
```

But this will cause exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        ...
```

I've tried to move drawable icon into `res/drawable-v21/` but this seems to be a problem with `LayoutInflater` itself.

I've tried to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` but this didn't work.

ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/layout_ico"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/t_icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/t_icon_size"
    android:background="@drawable/vector_ico"/>
```

Vector Icon(example of xml - cannot post exact icon):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="64dp"
    android:width="64dp"
    android:viewportHeight="600"
    android:viewportWidth="600" >
    <group
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:pivotX="300.0"
        android:pivotY="300.0"
        android:rotation="45.0" >
        <path
            android:name="vectorPath"
            android:fillColor="#000000"
            android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: martin show your gradle.build, gradle.properties and which theme you are using and last check weather your icon is in drawable folder, not in drawable 24 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated your gradle file while using appcompatImageView?

```
defaultConfig {
   ...
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

And in your layout

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    ... 
app:srcCompat="@drawable/something" />
```

Comment: Just use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
and select your drawable with srcCompat
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
...
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/something" />

Answer (score 0):

Other than include following line in your gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
 ...
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

You also need to add following line in your Application class:

```
class App : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ...
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
}
```

}